# MS Visual Studio 2019 Installation Issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am new to MS Visual Studio.I tried to install MS Visual studio 2019 professional so I downloaded vs_professional.exe. Visual studio installer started download around 75MB after getting message "Almost done.. Getting everything ready".Then automatically closed that window I don't know how to install or open Visual Studio Installer.Anybody can guide me to install MS Visual studio 2019 professional.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer right click as administrator.

Comment: Hi Anil. I restarted my system and run installer as administrator but still same issue happens.